# Some time cannot hide iOS keyboard and show UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

This is my `.h`

```
xxxx : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and my `.m`

```
UITextField *quarterPicker = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
[quarterPicker setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 370, 60, 30)];
[quarterPicker setText: @"Q1"];
quarterPicker.delegate = self;
```

and i use

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing"); 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(selectQuarterPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    return NO;  // Hide both keyboard and blinking cursor.
}
```

When i touch to my textField, i alway see this log `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`

But some time, my Picker doesn't show. I use : https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker to make Picker.

I find out that, when i swipe my textFiled, my picker will display.

How can i fix this?

**UPDATE:** i put my `UITextFiled` insite `UIScrollView`

Comment: Check inputView property in UITextField - assign your picker to it and text field will show it instead of keyboard with no more work on your side

Comment: in selectQuarterPicker, i show Picker like that: [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"INVESTMENT_SUM", nil)
                                            rows:colors
                                initialSelection:0
                                       doneBlock:done
                                     cancelBlock:cancel
                                          origin:sender];

Comment: You are adding the target for the touch event after the first touch is made. So only the second will work. Why add this event? You can simply show the picker inside shouldBeginEditing

Comment: because, when i use: [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(selectQuarterPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; when i select value in picker, my textField can show the value automatically

Comment: @LombaX: solved by replace sender by my textFiled. So please answer this question, and i will mark it as answer

Comment: Added the answer. But there are many other ways to do it ;-) (using a performSelector method, or replacing the textfield with a label and connecting the touch event in interface builder ecc ecc ). Good to hear that you solved :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the target for the touch event after the first touch is made. So only the second will work. Why add this event? You can simply show the picker inside shouldBeginEditing without adding a touch event

Something like

```
[self selectQuarterPicker:self]; //assuming the parameter is the sender as you commented
```